# XAMPP - Not able to display migrated WP site, message "No Access!"

Tags: wordpress, permissions, xampp, localhost

I've got a Wordpress website that I migrated from another server to my localhost. But when I try accessing it, all I get is a message "No Access!".I'm pretty sure that no such message is written within any of the website files or in its database, so I'm guessing it's a permissions issue. The site was moved from MAMP server to XAMPP running on Ubuntu Linux. I've been banging my head about it all day, so I decided to ask for help.

Comment: ServerFault is the site for system administration questions. I think the default Apache configuration denies all requests. Look for a `Deny from all` in `<Directory />` block in your `httpd.conf` and restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dan, I didn't know about that site. However (as usual :)), as soon as I asked for help, I've managed to fix it, and I will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite embarrassing. Turns out I didn't look into site files good enough. There was a function defined in functions.php saying:

```
/*
 * TEST MODE
 */

function test_mode(){
    $sid = session_id();
    if ( empty( $sid ) )
    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['access']) && $_GET['access'] == 'test'){
         $_SESSION['access'] = 'test';  
    }   

    if(!isset($_SESSION['access'])){
         die('No Access!');
    }
}
```

That was the cause of my trouble.